# Msg box when cell A not empty cell b mandatory to be filled in - currently msg box always displays

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA and have an XLS template where I'm trying to build in message box for users to fill in a cell in column B as mandatory if cell in column A is not blank before the template will allow saving. Currently it pops up the message whether the cell is blank or not and once you click ok, it saves anyway. Any advise on modifying the code below for the desired action?

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Sub Check()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10000")
    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell in column B requires user input in the format of PH_PSIxxxxxx"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `If cell.Offset(0,1).Value = "" Then` inside the existing `If` to check the corresponding B cell when A is not empty.

Comment: ^ also you forgot to declare `cell As Range`. Make sure the top of the module says `Option Explicit`. Side note, `Sub Check()` cannot be inside the scope of `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(...)`, there should be an `End Sub` between the two.

Comment: Are you looking for *BLANK* cells, or cells whose `Value` is an empty string? They are not the same thing... `Range.Value` is a `Variant`, so if you're looking for *empty* cells (no value, no formula, nothing whatsoever), then you want `If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then` for a condition. Note that `IsEmpty` will work fine if `cell.Value` contains a cell error value (e.g. `#N/A`, `#REF!`, etc.), whereas `If cell.value = "" Then` will blow up with a *type mismatch* if the cell value is an error.

Comment: ALSO you may want to include an `Exit For` after the Message Box, else if say 20 cells are not empty then the user will see 20 message boxes popping one after the other....

Comment: Great, thank you for the help, it works with the changes. I've added a pattern I want the users to adhere to so the final with your help works and looks like: